# Can anyone decrypt this?

Tags: cipher

My friend sent me this code, it's a simple substitution cipher:

> U FHGZE GYUE HTD ORGO RS G FIOS HROYDZHDE FTROD GZE U TRXE KUHTUZ YM
>   TGZE AOGUZF RS HTD ARXEDZ FGZE TRK SDK MDH TRK HTDM QODDB HTORIAT YM
>   SUZADOF HR HTD EDDB KTUXD U KDDB KTUXD U KDDB

If anyone could solve this I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it says

> I STAND AMID THE ROAR OF A SURF TORMENTED SHORE AND I HOLD WITHIN MY HAND GRAINS OF THE GOLDEN SAND HOW FEW YET HOW THEY CREEP THROUGH MY FINGERS TO THE DEEP WHILE I WEEP WHILE I WEEP

It is from

> *A Dream Within a Dream* by Edgar Allan Poe

Comment: Correct! I am still confused, how did you decrypt it so fast, I'm kind of new to cryptography so... any tips?

Comment: @Gerard You could try https://quipqiup.com/ - for this ciphertext it gives *almost* the right quote, which makes the true solution clear.